# Оптимизировать табличное пространство SYSTEM

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle, oracle12c

В ТП `SYSTEM` закончилось место. Но так, как часто удалялись, переименовывались и компилировались пакеты, то подозреваю, что индекс `I_SOURCE` сильно разросся и дефрагментирован. Обычные методы работы с индексами это ТП не допускает.

Подскажите, как можно сжать или добавить место в ТП `SYSTEM`?

Comment: у меня на 11g2 забивается засчет аудита в основном. Нужно точно определить, что разпухло и почистить, либо добавить ещё датафайл.

Comment: А как почистить? truncate table SYS.AUD$?

Comment: насколько помню, да, так.

Comment: Неужели ответ не помог? Или что то другое явилось причиной? Если да, дополните вопрос или дайте ответ.

Comment: Помог, спасибо. Закрутился, не отметил, извините.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tабличное пространство (ТП) `SYSTEM` не может переполнится. В этом ТП в принципе не может быть объектов БД, которые приведут к его переполнению. Здесь могут быть только объекты, которые создаются при установке БД, патчей, доп. модулей и ничего более.

---

Если под учётными записями `SYS` или `SYSTEM` были ошибочно созданы объекты БД, то самое оптимальное решение -- перенести их в другие схемы БД. Например, экспортировать их и [импортировать](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sutil/datapump-import-utility.html#GUID-619809A6-1966-42D6-9ACC-A3E0ADC36523]) с параметром:

```
impdp sys/pass REMAP_SCHEMA=sys:target_schema <др. параметры>
```

Как минимум нужно переместить подобные объекты в другие ТП, для `SYSTEM` это, как правило, `SYSAUX`.

Например, под уч.з. `SYS` создадим беcсмысленную таблицу , которая переполнит ТП:

```sql
create table bigtab (id number, name varchar2 (4000));
create index bigtab_idx on bigtab (name);
insert into bigtab 
    select level id, rpad ('A', 4000, 'A') name 
    from dual connect by level <= 10e10;
```

> ORA-01653: unable to extend table SYS.BIGTAB by 1024 in tablespace SYSTEM

Найти такие объекты можно так:

```sql
select 
    owner, segment_name, segment_type, tablespace_name, blocks, extents,
    round (bytes/1024/1024) sizemb 
from dba_segments 
where tablespace_name = 'SYSTEM' 
order by sizemb desc
fetch first 5 rows only;

OWNER SEGMENT_NAME     SEGMENT_TYPE       TABLESPACE_NAME      BLOCKS    EXTENTS     SIZEMB
----- ---------------- ------------------ ---------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
SYS   BIGTAB_IDX       INDEX              SYSTEM                57344        127        448
SYS   BIGTAB           TABLE              SYSTEM                37888        108        296
```

И переместить их в другое ТП:

```sql
alter table bigtab move tablespace sysaux;
alter index bigtab_idx rebuild tablespace sysaux;

select         
    owner, segment_name, segment_type, tablespace_name, blocks, extents,
    round (bytes/1024/1024, 2) sizemb 
from dba_segments
where segment_name like 'BIG%';

OWNER SEGMENT_NAME     SEGMENT_TYPE       TABLESPACE_NAME      BLOCKS    EXTENTS     SIZEMB
----- ---------------- ------------------ ---------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
SYS   BIGTAB           TABLE              SYSAUX                    8          1        .06
SYS   BIGTAB_IDX       INDEX              SYSAUX                    8          1        .06
```